# How to use min-width for "float:right" element in CSS?

Tags: html, css-float, css

Look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3r5/)

The html does not respect `min-width` as long as we have `float:right` in the CSS rules

```
.right {
    float:right;
    background:blue;
    min-width:400px;
}
```

If removing the `float:right` or changing it to `float:left`, then the html element will not be narrower than the `min-width`.

How we can use `min-width` for an element floated right?

**Screenshot**: As commented by some fellas, this is what I see on the latest version of Chromium on Debian.

[image]

As you can see the left side of the `div` including its content is invisible (in other words, outside the visible part).

Comment: I see it fine in the latest Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Even I see it fine on Chrome on iMac

Comment: perfectly working on firefox 20

Comment: @PedroEstrada I added a screenshot to show my problem.

Comment: It worked correctly for me too, latest Chrome on Win 8.

Comment: Works fine in latest Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Are you coding an `RTL` website? Make direction of `body` to `rtl` will solve your problem.

Comment: The screenshot shows that the div has been expanded so it is 400px wide. That's the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Quentin no he window width is smaller than `400px`. As you can see the div content is not visible (in the left side).

Comment: @All — Yes. That's the expected behaviour. The div content isn't visible because it is inside an element that you have explicitly said must be wider then the width you have set the window to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-floated div is doing just what it is told to in the original example: it is remaining at least 400px wide. If the viewport is reduced to less than 400px, part of the div is obscured, because it's not allowed to get any narrower than 400px. So the question is, what behavior do you really want here? Perhaps what you really want here is a non-floated wrapper element that has a min-width of 400px?

EDIT: Here's an example of how a non-floated wrapper will make it work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
body {
    background:red; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
    background:#e7e7e7; 
    min-height: 600px; 
    min-width: 400px;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    background:blue;
    min-width:400px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="right">
    TEST
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The wrapper could of course be colored red. I just made it gray so it was easy to see.

Comment: When reducing the window width to less than 400px, I expect horizontal scroll to make the entire div visible, like the case of `float:left`.

Comment: The browser will never scroll left of X co-ordinate 0.

Comment: I've updated my post with an example of how to do it with a non-floated wrapper element.

Answer (score 1):

div is a block level element, by default it will take up 100% space..

Alternatively if you want to see only 400px element instead of 100% width you can use `display: inline-block`, or specify a fixed width to it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3r5/1/)

Note: If you don't want to use `display: inline-block;` you can just keep it the way it is, if you minimize the window, you'll see a horizontal scroll bar so if you think that using `min-width` will only show element with a width of 400 px than you are wrong, it is `min` and not `max`

Comment: When you make `float` a block element, it acts as `inline-block` element, so there is no need to explicitly make element as `inline-block`.

Comment: @Mojtaba Exactly, but I just made that to explain him :)

Comment: It is not matter of using `inline-block`, I need to use `float:right`, as I want to display the div on the right side (when the window width is much larger than the `min-width`.

Comment: @All Ya so you can use it safely, there's no issue